# Rewrite from index.php?type=search&q=* to search/?q=*

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

The URL I want to rewrite is:

> `http://domain.com/index.php?type=search&q=something`

to

> `http://domain.com/search/?q=something`

I have created the .htaccess file and put this code for rewrite:

> ```
> RewriteEngine On  
> RewriteRule ^search/?q=(.*)$ index.php?type=search&q=$1 [QSA,L]
> ```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Isn't this backwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use that:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^search/$ index.php?type=search&q=%1 [L]
```